# Count number of occurances in array until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "header": true
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-002",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-003",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-002",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P002",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P002-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P004",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P004-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P005",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P005-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P006-000",
        "nest": 0
    }
]
```

This array is basically some meta data for another array, which looks like this,

```
[
    [
        "ID",
        "SYMBOL",
        "SIDE",
        "SIZE",
        "PRICE",
        "FILL",
        "NOTICE",
        "MID",
        "STATE",
        "SENT",
        "COMMENT",
        "PID"
    ],
    [
        "P000",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1531,
        -9.6979699543,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P000-000",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        22,
        -9.985,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "P000-002",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        250,
        -9.874,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "P000-003",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1,
        -9.945,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "P000-001",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1259,
        -9.658,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "P001",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        333,
        -1.8855675676,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P001-000",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        99,
        -1.865,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        "98.8mm JPM PB",
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "P001-001",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        45,
        -1.866,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "P001-002",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        189,
        -1.901,
        7,
        null,
        -1.901,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "P002",
        "MAX-FVFLY-M-17/83-",
        "S",
        1500,
        -0.658,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P002-000",
        "MAX-FVFLY-M-17/83-",
        "S",
        1500,
        -0.658,
        null,
        "OUT 0.001",
        -0.657,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P002"
    ],
    [
        "P003",
        "MAX-FVFLY-M-17/83-",
        "B",
        2722,
        -10.6373335783,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P003-000",
        "MAX-FVFLY-M-17/83-",
        "B",
        1200,
        -10.62,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P003"
    ],
    [
        "P003-001",
        "MAX-FVFLY-M-17/83-",
        "B",
        1522,
        -10.651,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P003"
    ],
    [
        "P004",
        "03-May",
        "B",
        12,
        -11,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P004-000",
        "03-May",
        "B",
        12,
        -11,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P004"
    ],
    [
        "P005",
        "Parent row out of order",
        "B",
        12,
        -11,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "P005-000",
        "Parent row out of order",
        "B",
        12,
        -11,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P005"
    ],
    [
        "P006-000",
        "No Parent row",
        "B",
        99,
        0,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P006"
    ]
]
```

Each index of the second array matches to the index of the first array I loop through the second array, and when I am looping I want to look at the first array, and see whether the matching index is `nest:0` and if it is how more indexes occur until the next `nest:0`

So I were to this for the array index 1 I would expect to see 3 returned as there are 3 indexes between the first occurrences of `nest:0` (at index 1) and next occurrence of `nest:0`

If a nest attribute is 0 it means it's a parent, if a nest object is 1 it's means its a child. What I am wanting to is access the above array at a certain index and count the number of `nest:1` until the next `nest:0` this way I can work how many children that parent has.

To count the number of occurrences on `nest:0` I can do thing like this,

`const count = array.filter((obj) => obj.nest === 1).length;`

This will give me the number child rows in the entire row, but what I just want to count the number of child rows from a certain index until next occurrence of `nest:0`

For example how would I count the number of `nest:1` from the `nest:0` at index 1 until following `nest:0`?

Comment: I understand your objective, but what should the output look like? How will each count be displayed? As a new property on each parent? Or a simple array of the counts?

Comment: note that the findIndex predicate takes a second param which is the index of the element passed. your condition could say `(el, index) => index>startIndex && el.nest===0`

Comment: @zer00ne what I am wanting to do is just returned the number of children I have given some more background in my questions.

Answer (score 2):

By simply iterating over the array:

```
let count = 0;
for (let i = index; i < array.length && array[i].nest ! == 0; i++)
    count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array starting from the provided index and keep updating the count until a `0` is encountered.

```js
const data = [{ nest: 1 }, { nest: 1 }, { nest: 0 }, { nest: 1 }, { nest: 1 }];

const sol = (data, index) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = index; i < data.length && data[i].nest; i++) {
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
};

console.log(sol(data, 0)); // 2
console.log(sol(data, 1)); // 1
console.log(sol(data, 2)); // 0
console.log(sol(data, 3)); // 2
```

If you have to make this query again and again for different indices then you can precompute the count at all indices beforehand, as shown below:

```js
const data = [{ nest: 1 }, { nest: 1 }, { nest: 0 }, { nest: 1 }, { nest: 1 }];

const counts = [];
for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (data[i].nest) {
    counts.unshift(1 + (counts.length && counts[0]));
  } else {
    counts.unshift(0);
  }
}

const queries = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(queries.map((index) => counts[index])); // [ 2, 1, 0, 2, 1 ]
```